# Apache2 VirtualHost : deny root URL but allow path

Tags: regex, apache, apache2, virtualhost

I am using below to block accessing the root URL... and trying to only allow access if visited path or with anything after root domain...

```
# Redirect root domain to a 403 Forbidden error
<Location "/">
   Require all denied
</Location>
```

But below LocationMatch is not working... its allowing root URL and everything... I might be missing a very small thing, help here please!!!

```
<LocationMatch "^/.+$">
   Require all granted
</LocationMatch>
```